# Копирование отрицательных элементов в массив

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо написать код, копирующую один массив в другой следующим образом: сначала копируются последовательно все элементы, большие 0, затем последовательно все элементы, равные 0, а затем последовательно все элементы, меньшие 0. Как это сделать?
Вот моя неудачная попытка реализовать эту задачу:

```
        int[] arr = new int[100];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            int randNum = random.nextInt(800) - 400;
            arr[i] = randNum;
        }
        int[] newArr = new int[100];
        int[] positive = new int[100];
        int[] negative = new int[100];
        int[] zerro = new int[100];
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > 0)
            {
                positive[j] = arr[j];
                // System.arraycopy(arr, arr[j], newArr, 0, 100); Not works!
            }
            if (arr[j] == 0)
            {
                zerro[j] = arr[j];
            }
            if (arr[j] < 0)
            {
                negative[j] = arr[j];
            }
        }
        System.arraycopy(positive, 0, negative, 0, 100);   // Not works!
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positive));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(zerro));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negative));
//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
```

Comment: Если не секрет, где вы берете такие задания?

Comment: А вы бы посмотрели в качестве отладки через `System.out.println` сразу после объявления массивов и до цикла и посмотрели бы что там в них.....а также во время выполнения цикла..... а также просто отдельно все закомментить и оставить например только `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(positive));` ......... что выведет? ........... это подсказка ..........................а еще копирование из позитива в негатив..........это вроде не правильная затея .......`System.arraycopy(positive, 0, negative, 0, 100);   // Not works!` .... еще как works.... просто почему вы решили что не works?

Comment: А если вам все равно каким путем идти, но достичь результата, то можно просто написать вот так `Arrays.sort(arr);` и первоначальный массив будет отсортирован))  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо создать свою имплементацию (версию) интерфейса `Comparator<Integer>` и переопределить метод `compare`:

```
private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if (o1 > 0 & o2 != 0) {
                return o1 - o2;
            }
            if (o1 > 0 & o2 == 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o1 < 0 & o2 < 0) {
                return o2 - o1;
            }
            if (o1 < 0 & o2 >= 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o1 == 0) {
                return o2;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

А затем использовать его по своему усмотрению. Например:

```
CustomComparator customComparator = new CustomComparator();
List<Integer> sortedList = Stream.of(12, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 18, 0, -123, -22, -23).sorted(customComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```